# Use of comma before AT

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, commas

is the use of comma appropriate in the following sentence

**The UK had the highest amount of tea import, at around 80,000 tonnes.**

or should I write it without the use of a comma?

**The UK had the highest amount of tea import at around 80,000 tonnes.**

Comment: Either is acceptable. It depends on if you want the tonnage to be essential or nonessential information.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better if you would use a dash:

> The UK had the highest amount of tea import — at around 80,000 tonnes.

Comment: That's not a dash (—), that's a hyphen (-).